# C# Sqlite Select

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I`m using this code to read from a sqlite table and add the row where it is to the DataGridview. The problem is that if I want to add the same item more than once, it will only add once. I want to be able to add as many items as I want.

```
    private SQLiteConnection sql_con;
    private SQLiteCommand sql_cmd;
    private SQLiteDataAdapter DB;
    private DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    private DataTable DT = new DataTable();

    private void btnAdicionaProduto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cmdInsereProdutos = "select codigo,Nome,Unidade,Valor from Produtos where codigo = @codigo";
         InsereProdutosCaixa(cmdInsereProdutos);
        if (dataGridViewProdutos.RowCount > 0)
        {
            dataGridViewProdutos.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dataGridViewProdutos.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dataGridViewProdutos.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dataGridViewProdutos.Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewProdutos.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                int colw = dataGridViewProdutos.Columns[i].Width;
                dataGridViewProdutos.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
                dataGridViewProdutos.Columns[i].Width = colw;
            }
            txtCodigo.Text = "";
            txtCodigo.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void InsereProdutosCaixa(string txtQuery)
    {
        try
        {
            SetConnection();
            sql_con.Open();
            sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
            sql_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", txtCodigo.Text);
            sql_cmd.CommandText = txtQuery;
            SQLiteDataReader readerProduto = sql_cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DT.Load(readerProduto);
            dataGridViewProdutos.DataSource = DT;
            sql_con.Close();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "ERRO");
        }

    }
```

Comment: When your query "select codigo,Nome,Unidade,Valor from Produtos where codigo = @codigo" returns more than one result, do they all appear in the datagridview? It's not 100% clear to me what your actual issue is?

Comment: Yes, if I search for code 1 and it finds it it sends it to the datagridview them if I search for code 2 and it sends it to the datagridview but if I search for 1 again it wont ad it there will be only one row for code 1

Comment: If the datasource changes, thats what will be displayed in the data view grid. I think what you want to do is change your SQL select statement so that it pulls back *all* of the data you want. Then set the data source. Is that your issue?

Comment: No Robnik, I`ll tryie to explain better, I have a table with code 1 ,2 and 3. if I run the InsereProdutosCaixa with the code 1, the product with code 1 will  be added to the dataGridView them if I run it again with code 2, the datagridView will have the produc 1 from the first search and product 2 from the second search, now if I do a third run now with code 1 again it wont add the product with code 1 again. the DatagridView will only have products 1 and 2 not 1 ,2 and 1. Sorry if i don`t make sense some times but it is har for me to explain in english